# Including headers from custom framework in XCode

Tags: xcode, frameworks, include, header, search-path

**Am I supposed to adjust `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` or `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` when I add custom frameworks to the project?**

I have `MainProject.xcodeproject` that links `SomeFramework.framework` that's simply dragged from "Products" in `SomeFramework.xcodeproject` to "Link with Binary Libraries" build phase in main project.

Framework contains all required headers in its `Headers` directory. However, in my project I can't simply use:

```
#import <SomeFramework.h> // I'm pretty sure this file exists
```

to include this header. Build fails "No such file or directory". Compiler flags include `-F…/SomeFramework/build/Release` and that directory contains framework with `Headers` directory symlink in it.

(BTW: this is for Mac OS X. I don't care about iPhone.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just adding the path to the directory containing the framework to FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS will work. Unless it's a typo, your problem seems to be

```
#import <SomeFramework.h>
```

which should be

```
#import <SomeFramework/SomeFramework.h>
```

Comment: It wasn't a typo! I'm half-there. Now the second problem is that `SomeFramework/SomeFramework.h` contains `#import <SomeFrameworksOtherHeader.h>`. Is that the same error in the framework too?

Comment: Yes, in that case it should be #import "SomeFrameworksOtherHeader.h"

Comment: Hi. thanks, that answer helped me out in my project :) but i have another question regarding this subject. with #include<MyFramework/MyHeader.h> works fine, but i wanted to have only #include<MyHeader.h> and this time it doesn't find the header..  And with FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS containing the directory of the framework doesn't change anything.. any thoughts? :) thks!

Comment: Well i actually got it working if I set the path to the Headers symlink of my framework in the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS, but this solution is not ideal.. Is there any other way? thks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you should start another question.

Comment: And what is the path??? Surely you don't mean an absolute path then release/debug wouldn't work anymore.